# Best way to store last name/business name in a customer table

Tags: database, field

I have a customer table where I'm currently storing:

- Last Name
- First Name
- Middle Name
- Business Name
- Entity Type (Business or Individual)
- Address, Phone, etc.

If the customer is a business, I'm currently storing the business name in a separate field. I'm already storing the entity type, so is it even necessary to store the business name in a separate field? In my search query, I'm using "WHERE last_name LIKE '%$var%' OR business_name LIKE '%$var%'" which is probably overkill. Should I keep it the way I have it, or should I consolidate the business name into the last name field? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to put the business name into the column for the last name,
because after you select, you recognize if its a company if it has no first name.

further you only need one logic to put your name into a string.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually create different tables

```
1. for people
1. for companies
1. for people - company relation
```

This offers maximum flexibility later on, for instance you could have a user that belongs to a business and buys either for him of for his business.

Mihai

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: if you use last_name and business_name like this you don't need to use two fields. Create only one field (instead of this two) called name. You can enter either 'last name' or 'business name' value there so you have SQL like this:

```
WHERE name like '%$var%'
```

In case you have real person you will have name, first_name, middle_name filled in.
In case you have business you will have only name.

And of course entity_type will distinguish between them.